# Let $(s_n)$ be a convergent sequence of real numbers such that $s_n \neq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}s_n=s\neq 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Prove that $\sup \{\frac{1}{|s_n|} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}>0$

Any help on getting this proof started would be appreciated. I know it must be related to proving that $\inf \{|s_n|:n \in \mathbb{N}\}>0$ but the $\frac{1}{|s_n|}$ is what is throwing me off.

Comment: Wait, how about $\sup \{ 1/|s_n| : n \in \mathbb{N}\} \ge 1/|s_n| > 0$ because $s_1 \ne 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $l := \sup_{n \geq 1}|s_{n}|^{-1}$ and suppose $l \leq 0$. Then for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is some $n \geq 1$ such that
$$
l - \varepsilon < |s_{n}|^{-1} \leq l \leq 0.
$$
But, since $|s_{n}|^{-1} > 0$ for all $n \geq 1$,
$\to \gets$.

Comment: @chad, This proof uses only the definition of supremum (using other axioms this "definition" may be derived as a theorem, but).

Comment: What does that pair of arrows mean? Does it stand for "contradiction"?

Comment: Yes, maybe the notation has not yet been widely spread enough :)

Comment: I see, good to know. :) And I do like it, pretty sure I'll adopt it, thanks. And +1 by the way.

Comment: Thank you for this, this really helped

Answer (score 1):

Note that a convergent sequence is bounded.

Let $K>0$ denote the bound of $s_n$ so that ${1 \over |s_n|} \ge {1\over K} > 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Since this inequality holds for all $n$ it follows that 
$$\sup_{n \in \mathbb N}{1 \over |s_n|} \ge {1\over K} > 0$$